# Calling a fragment and getting the id in the RecyclerView adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a list using the RecyclerView, what I want is that when I click on the list item, it opens a fragment, I've been searching and I only found it with an activity, but I'm working only with fragments, if I use activity it disappears with my action bar, it's all set in the fragment.

This is my adapter class:

```
    public class CreditCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CreditCardHolder> {

    private final List<CreditCard> creditList;

    public CreditCardAdapter(List<CreditCard> creditList) {
        this.creditList = creditList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CreditCardHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.credit_card_item, parent, false);
        return new CreditCardHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CreditCardHolder holder, int position) {
        CreditCard credit = creditList.get(position);
        String flag = credit.getFlag();
        holder.flag.setText(flag);
        String owner = credit.getOwner();
        holder.owner.setText(owner);
        String valueLimit = String.format("%.2f", credit.getLimit());
        holder.limit.setText(valueLimit.replace(".", ","));
        holder.creditCardId = credit.getId();

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //Method on click
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return creditList.size();
    }
}
```

I need to send the credit card id to the fragment, to call the controller and get the information from the database, I tried it with the intent, but it only worked if I call the activity with startActivity(intent).

So here it is the fragment class:

```
public class InfoCreditCardFragment extends Fragment {

    public InfoCreditCardFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_credit_card, container, false);


        String id; //Here I need the id from the Adapter

        TextView flagInfoTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.flagInfoTxt);
        TextView ownerInfoTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.ownerInfoTxt);

        CreditCard cc = CreditCardController.getWithId(id);
        flagInfoTxt.setText(cc.getFlag());
        ownerInfoTxt.setText(cc.getOwner());


        return view;
    }
}
```

If anyone knows anything to help, please, I'm desperate.

Comment: You can use `FragmentManager` to replace a fragment. You can pass your id as a `Bundle`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#java

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to go to the fragment using this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("id", holder.creditCardId);

InfoCreditCardFragment fragment = new InfoCreditCardFragment();
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

And inside the fragment I just get the bundle with "getArguments().getString("id");"

Comment: Never mind, I got it after hitting my head on the keyboard hahahah, figured out how to use a Bundle.

Comment: Can you add more info about your issues with the bundle and steps to diagnose and resolve that in your answer please?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).